# Commonly used alias for sqlalchemy module when using import module_name as module_alias

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For some libraries such as `numpy` and `pandas` we usually import them with the `np` and `pd` aliases.
I am asking whether there is a widely known alias for the sqlalchemy module in python as in

```
import module_name as module_alias
```

I have already searched in google without great success:

```
site:docs.sqlalchemy.org "import sqlalchemy as"
```

So far, I have seen some people are using these two:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy as db
```

Comment: `import sqlalchemy as sa` is more common. To me, `import sqlalchemy as db` is misleading because `db` suggests a database object, and SQLAlchemy is a *module* for working with SQL databases, not a database itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite in sqlalchemy they do not use it, in the alembic documentation it's often used `import sqlalchemy as sa` for importing sqlalchemy.

Alembic is a lightweight database migration tool for usage with the SQLAlchemy Database Toolkit for Python.

Answer (score 1):

In example on Pandas website:

```
import pandas as pd
```

That is the same with numpy.

Other aspects: PyQt5, PySide2 often use:

```
from PySide2.xxx import Yyy.
```

Back to sqlalchemy:The example is usually written as:

```
from sqlalchemy import Abc
from sqlalchemy.xxx import Yyy
```

Why are you worried about that.If you insist on searching then I think this will work for you.

```
"import sqlalchemy as sa" site:https://*.sqlalchemy.org
```

Comment: I prefer not to use the approach from sqlalchemy because I want to avoid name collisions when I import things in python.